# Definition of weak derivative.

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, weak-derivatives

For $u \in C^1(\Omega)$ and $\phi \in C_0^{\infty}(\Omega)$ one has
$$
\begin{split}
\int_{\Omega}\nabla|u| \phi dx &=-\int_{\Omega}|u|\nabla \phi dx\\
 &=-\int_{[u>0]}u\nabla \phi dx +\int_{[u<0]}u\nabla \phi dx\\
&=\int_{[u>0]}\nabla u \phi dx-\int_{[u<0]} \nabla u \phi dx \\&=\int_{\Omega}\operatorname{sign}(u) \nabla u \phi dx.
\end{split}
$$
For $u \in W^{1,1}({\Omega})$ set
$$
\nabla|u|=\operatorname{sign}(u) \nabla u,
$$ 
which is well-defined, since $\operatorname{sign}(u) \in L^{\infty}(\Omega)$.
If $C^1(\Omega)\ni u_m \rightarrow u \in W^{1,1}(\Omega)$ one finds
$$
\begin{split}
\bigg|\int_{\Omega}\operatorname{sign}(u) \nabla u \phi dx &-\int_{\Omega}\operatorname{sign}(u_m) \nabla u_m \phi dx\bigg| \\
&\leq \bigg|\int_{\Omega}(\operatorname{sign}(u)-\operatorname{sign}(u_m)) \nabla u \phi dx\bigg|+\bigg|\int_{\Omega}(\operatorname{sign}(u_m) (\nabla u-\nabla u_m) \phi dx\bigg|\\
&\leq \int_{\Omega}|\operatorname{sign}(u)-\operatorname{sign}(u_m)| |\nabla u ||\phi| dx+\int_{\Omega}|\nabla u- \nabla u_m||\phi| dx
\end{split}
$$
this goes to zero for m to infinite. This confirms $|u|$ having a weak derivative $\operatorname{sign}(u)\nabla u$.

**Question**. I only know this definition with $\bigg|\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}\bigg|$: why is $\nabla$ used ?

Comment: I think we would need $$\left |\frac{\partial_i u}{\partial x_i}\right |$$.  Are you sure all the absolute values are where they should be?

Comment: thanks for help , yes

Comment: Oh , you are right I did a typo .

Comment: Are you sure you've written what you intend? Specifically, gradient $\nabla$ produces vector-valued functions, and you intend to multiply them by the indicated scalar-valued functions? It's perfectly well-defined, but is an unusual thing to do...